# Server Error in '/' Application Cannot convert a char value to money

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, casting, type-conversion

I am running the following stored precedure.
The result set is binded on a gridView control.

```
@EmbossLine varchar(20),

@TransactionTypeID int,

@DateFrom datetime,

@DateTo datetime

AS

Select 

pt.TransactionDate,
m.MerchantName1,
pt.TerminalID,
pt.SequenceNumber,
tt.TransactionType,
case TT.TransactionTypeID when 0 then PT.TotalAmount else 'null' end 'PointsEarned',
case TT.TransactionTypeID when 2 then PT.TotalAmount else 'null' end 'PointsRedemeed'
from POS_Transactions PT 
inner join TransactionType TT on TT.TransactionTypeID = PT.TransactionTypeID
inner join CardBalance CB on CB.PAN = PT.PAN
inner join Terminal T on T.TerminalID = PT.TerminalID
inner join Merchant M on M.MerchantID = T.MerchantID
where 
(PT.TransactionDate>=@DateFrom and PT.TransactionDate<=@DateTo)
and (PT.TransactionTypeID = @TransactionTypeID or @TransactionTypeID ='-999')
and(PT.PAN=@EmbossLine or PT.PAN='-999')
order by PT.TransactionDate desc
```

Actually what Im trying to do is, I want to print `null` whenever my `TransactionTypeID` is not equal to `0` or `2`. but it throws a runtime exception

```
Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.
```

I know it is a conversion issue and want to know how can I print some value when my conditions evaluates to false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change these two lines:

```
case TT.TransactionTypeID when 0 then PT.TotalAmount else 'null' end 'PointsEarned',
case TT.TransactionTypeID when 2 then PT.TotalAmount else 'null' end 'PointsRedemeed'
```

to this:

```
case TT.TransactionTypeID when 0 then PT.TotalAmount else null end 'PointsEarned',
case TT.TransactionTypeID when 2 then PT.TotalAmount else null end 'PointsRedemeed'
```

You want to produce a `null` value in your `else` condition. You are currently producing the word `'null'` which is where the conversion is failing - you can't convert the word (`char` data type) `'null'` to the money datatype.

EDIT:

You will need to cast the values to a string to do this. But that would mean instead of returning the money datatype to your client, you would be returning a string.

This sort of thing should really be handled in the client and not in SQL Server. In anycase try this to convert everything to a string:

```
case TT.TransactionTypeID when 0 then Cast(PT.TotalAmount as varchar(50)) else 'null' end 'PointsEarned',
case TT.TransactionTypeID when 2 then Cast(PT.TotalAmount as varchar(50)) else 'null' end 'PointsRedemeed'
```

Comment: Tried this already. the cell will be empty but I want to print 'null' or say any text

Comment: Thats What I was looking for. Actually I want my stored procedure to be able to do this. I dont want to add any logic in my asp.net code for this. It works absolutely fine

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```
case TT.TransactionTypeID when 0 then cast(PT.TotalAmount as varchar) else 'null' end 'PointsEarned',
case TT.TransactionTypeID when 2 then cast(PT.TotalAmount as varchar) else 'null' end 'PointsRedemeed'
```

just cast `TotalAmount` to varchar, it should work.

Comment: Don't use `varchar` without specifying a length - it will default to a length of 1 !

Comment: @Barry - I am somehow aware about it. :-) although in my poc, it still displays the value even if the length is more than 1 char.